# Generate all matroids on a given groundset in Sage

Tags: combinatorics, sage

I would like to give Sage some groundset and have it generate all possible matroids on that groundset. This is possible in e.g. Macaulay2; does any analogous method exist for Sage's matroids package?

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful. It provides Sage code to get the matroids from a catalog file.
https://zenodo.org/records/6825419

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35412715)